# Best way to divide a larger dataframe into two organized dataframes?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(101L, 102L, 201L, 202L, 
301L, 302L), bin1 = c(263L, 276L, 270L, 163L, 
268L, 233L), bin2 = c(53L, 42L, 42L, 146L, 57L, 33L
), bin3 = c(11L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 59L), bin4 = c(1L, 
0L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 4L), class = "data.frame"))

data <- as.data.frame(data)
data <- data[-c(6)]
```

I'm trying to organize the dataframe into two separate dataframes using this method:

```
One <- grep('01$', data$ID)
Two <- grep('02$', data$ID)

DataOne <- subset(data, Reduce(`|`, lapply(data[One], `>=`, 0)))
```

This yields the undefined columns selected error. Ok, fine. So, I try this method:

```
DataOne <- subset(data, select=data[One])
```

I get the error "invalid subscript type 'list'" So it won't work on listed data then.

I'm basically trying to create two dataframes from one while also retaining the original. I was hoping the `grep()` function would work.

I'm hoping to get this:

```
ID  bin1 bin2 bin3
101 263  53   11
201 270  42   7
301 268  57   0
```

for the dataframe DataOne, for example.

Comment: @akrun I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of two datasets.  If needed to create multiple objects, can use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
lst1 <- setNames(split(data, grepl('01$', data$ID)),
       paste0("Data", c("One", "Two")))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
DataOne
#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#2 102  276   42   12    0
#4 202  163  146    7    3
#6 302  233   33   59    4

DataTwo
#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#1 101  263   53   11    1
#3 201  270   42    7   10
#5 301  268   57    0    0
```

NOTE: This would also work as a general solution when there are more than two groups and limits the number of lines of code to just a a single line with `split`

i.e. if there are many groups, we can take the last two substring characters

```
split(data,  sub(".*(..)$", "\\1", data$ID))
```

-output

```
#$`01`
#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#1 101  263   53   11    1
#3 201  270   42    7   10
#5 301  268   57    0    0

#$`02`
#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#2 102  276   42   12    0
#4 202  163  146    7    3
#6 302  233   33   59    4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `One` and `Two` as row index to subset `data`.

```
DataOne <- data[One, ]
DataTwo <- data[Two, ]
DataOne

#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#1 101  263   53   11    1
#3 201  270   42    7   10
#5 301  268   57    0    0

DataTwo
#   ID bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4
#2 102  276   42   12    0
#4 202  163  146    7    3
#6 302  233   33   59    4
```

This would create two dataframes (`DataOne`, `DataTwo`) keeping the original one (`data`) as it is.